# How to load a .txt file and erase after delimiter on each line

Tags: vb.net

I am loading a .txt file that contains around a thousand names in a firstName:lastName format. I only need the firstnames for what I'm doing right now. How can I strip the entire list, which is displayed in a listbox, and display first names only?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please Select a File"
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:temp"
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
    Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
    strm = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()
    TextBox2.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextBox2.Text))
End Sub
```

Comment: What format is the data in? Are the first names and surnames separated by a colon as you've said or by a space?

Comment: Seperated by a colon, no spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split each line into a sub-array, and return the first element into a new array

```
Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
    Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
    strm = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()
    TextBox2.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(
        System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextBox2.Text).
        Select(Function(l) l.Split(":"c).FirstOrDefault()).
        ToArray())
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for such a quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) to break each line apart at the delimiter and use the first part returned:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(
    System.IO.File.ReadLines(TextBox2.Text).Select(
        Function(x) x.Split(":"c)(0)
    ).ToArray()
)
```

I used `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines`, since it may be a little more efficient, but it looks like `AddRange` needs an array anyway, hence the `ToArray` call.

However, it really depends on what you are going to do once you have the items in the list.  It may be better to create a class for the full names and read the file into a list of those, and then bind using `DataSource` and `DisplayMember`.